# Node different require behaviour same app different servers

Tags: node.js, express

I have a project (express js) in which the main `app.js` has its declarations, i.e:

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
    main = require('./routes/main'),
    config = require('./config.js'),
...
```

So in a file like `routes/main.js` I could access the properties of config. I've also installed my express js on another server so all of a sudden a route in `/routes/main.js` tells me

```
ReferenceError: config is not defined
```

So if I redeclare it in there, now there isn't a null reference error but everything becomes `undefined`.

Both of the servers are running the script the same way (via `forever`). I am using a full path when starting scripts, but it does work fine on one server (centos) and not the other (ubuntu), but there aren't any other differences.

Comment: Try with fs to list your current folder. What does routes/mains.js contain?

Comment: Well, it seems that it is not a problem in importing (otherwise you would get `Error: Cannot find module './config.js'`). Are you using same versions of Node? I guess that we would need the actual code which throws that error.